# Set text to label in birt .rptdesign file using ReportDesignHandle

Tags: java, birt

I'm trying to programatically fill in a template that can be moved around and then the file uploaded to my program. I've been searching for a while and there seems to be only old answers where the old API allowed a simple setText like this:

`designHandle.findElement("ValueName").setText("text");`

I also found out that `ITextItemInstance` is able to setText like I want, however it only seems to be used when creating new instances of labels, not editing existing ones.

I'm using Birt 4.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the book [Integrating and Extending BIRT](https://books.google.com/books?id=aIjZ4FYJOQkC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=settext&f=false) page 296:

```
//Access the label by name.
LabelHandle headerLabel = (LabelHandle) design.findElement("Header Label");
try {
headerLabel.setText("Updated " + headerLabel.getText());
} catch (Exception e) {
// Handle the exception
}
```

`design` being a `ReportDesignHandle` object.